# WPF: OnApplyTemplate is not called anymore when I moved code into another DLL

Tags: wpf

Let's try to explain it clearly.

I've got a custom control built as a WPF application and it works fine. I've moved all the code into a external DLL. After this change, when I load the application, the method **OnApplyTemplate()** is not called any more and the control is not rendered either

- I've try with *Generic.xaml* file is into a *Themes* directory (with capital *T*) in the root of the DLL which has the control and/or a *Themes* directory into the StartUp project.
- If this info is important here's where I've found the control: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFOutlookCalendar.aspx
- The settings of the project is

  - Output type: **Class Library**
  - Target framework: **.Net Framework 4**
- I've create a simple DLL project and I've added the references manually

Do you have any idea about the solution?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What kind of DLL? What kind of project template did you use? If you had to create the Generic.xaml on your own, it was propably the wrong one. Try User Control or Custom Control Library. I still have yet to figure out, how to change an existing simple library project into an WPF capable one.

Comment: I've just created a simple library and I've added the library needed for WPF. I edit my post to indicates theses pieces of info

Comment: Ok, now remove that project and try again with a Custom Control Library found in the project template.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in that Window is not calling OnApplyTemplate in .NET 4 - unfortunately switching to a Custom Control is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main difference between a standard Wpf Applicaton and a WPF Custom Control library are the following lines of code.

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
//(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
// or application resource dictionaries)
ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
//(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
// app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```

Adding these lines of code to your Assembly should fix your bug.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to dowhilefor, I've found the solution!

I've recreated a new library as a **WPF Custom Control Library** and it works.

It is a little overkill to recreate a new project so if someone can explain to me how to reconfigure an existing project, it'd be very nice ;)