# OnApplyTemplate() not being called when control template is changed via a style

Tags: wpf, templates

I have a control whose template is changed via a style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:MyControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ControlType" Value="Type1">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Type1.Template}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ControlType" Value="Type2">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Type2.Template}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

I need to hook up to the visual tree, but for some reason `MyControl.OnApplyTemplate()` is never called when the template change is triggered. It only ever fires once at control creation.

I have also tried `OnTemplateChanged()`, but this doesn't fire either.

Comment: Check out the answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757932/wpf-onapplytemplate-is-not-called-anymore-when-i-moved-code-into-another-dll - do they help?